Solang: Check nft metaplex metadata
I want to check if NFT belongs to a verified collection address, how can I do that in Solang?
For if user wants to deposit nft to the contract, that nft should belong to only the defined collection address. I don't know how to fetch metadata from the mint address, does AccountInfo contain metadata?
